# Error: bcrypt_lib.node is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, bcrypt, win32-process

I have a nodejs project on my windows machine. Where upon attempting to run the project this error appears involving bcrypt and win32.

[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

```
Error: \\?\C:\Users\owner\desktop\msci444\no-scraps\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Users\owner\desktop\msci444\no-scraps\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\owner\desktop\msci444\no-scraps\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

[pt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBWes.png)

Comment: Hi, according to this response https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/635#issuecomment-464506366 you need to run => npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source

Comment: Please update the question title with `bcrypt_lib.node is not a valid Win32 application`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are different possibilities how to resolve:

- `npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source` (as stated in the comments already) check that your node version for recompiling matches the test/production version
- `npm install node-pre-gyp -g`   then   `npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source`
- Delete the folder containing npm-bcrypt on the deployment server inside your project folder node_modules (..programs\server\node_modules). On the deployment server, run `npm install bcrypt`

Hope one helpsyou

Comment: Removing node_modules folder and reinstalling it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

I was getting this error in my windows environment: previously I was running the project under windows subsystem linux, and once I needed to debug it in visual studio code, the environment started the windows version of node, which in turn was wondering about non win32 binaries of bcrypt library.

Removing the `node_modules` and then reinstalling them `npm i` solved the issue.

Comment: best answer easily solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Remove or delete `node_modules` and reinstall all packages.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you swap files from one operating system to another. Eg copy/move project files from MacOS to Windows or Linux. To fix it delete the node modules files and do a clean `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem. I was able to run my project changing my code in the following way:

From: `//import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';`

To: `//import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs;`

and installing dependencies: `npm i bcryptjs --save`

Comment: bcryptjs doesn't receive updates since 2017. I would not recommend using this.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps;

Step 1: Expand `node_modules`

Step : Delete `bcrypt` package

Step 3: Run `npm install` or `yarn install`

Step 4: Restart server

Comment: thanks, I was struggling to run my server. By the way, how do you get this kind of solution?

Comment: @Mahantesh.N.Hadimani. I think npm packages that includes python files (there are python files inside bcrypt package) need to build using node-gyp or node-pre-gyp. In my case, I linked my project directory to a (linux) docker container and ran it inside docker (I think all node modules and bcrypt were built using linux version of node-gyp/node-pre-gyp). Then after ran it locally without using docker (without removing node modules) I got the error. Then I restart server locally after removing bcrypt and running yarn install. After that I didn't get the error :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue; I installed bcrypt using the WSL subsystem with npm i bcrypt which I assume installs an architecturally specific version which doesn't mesh with Windows. I had nodemon running on my local machine's terminal and when I tried running my app, it kept crashing.

So I deleted the node_modules folder and then used npm i on my local machine's terminal instead to install the packages and it worked without a hitch!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue; I installed bcrypt using the WSL subsystem with `npm i bcrypt` which I assume installs an architecturally specific version which doesn't mesh with Windows. I had nodemon running on my local machine's terminal and when I tried running my app, it kept crashing.

So I deleted the `node_modules` folder and then used `npm i` on my local machine's terminal instead to install the packages and it worked without a hitch!

*(I have nodemon on my local machine because supposedly mongod doesn't work well with WSL)*

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to add node path to environments.
for me in WHM server:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/
```